# Issue with finding first image source in Wordpress post (using regex and PHP)

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, loops

I am having issues with this regex, which is finding the source of each image in a Wordpress post. At the moment, for example, the first image source outputs as https://www.telecomsworldplc.co.uk/h and not https://www.telecomsworldplc.co.uk/advice/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/globalBusiness.jpg...

Any ideas why it is doing this? The code is here...

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 4
));
$j = 0;

$wpArray = array();
$wpImageArray = array();

foreach($recent_posts as $wpposts){
   preg_match( "<img.*?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", $wpposts['post_content'], $matches2 ) ;
   $wpimg = $matches2[1];
   $wpImageArray = $wpimg;
   $wpArray[] = $wpposts['post_title'];
}

$k = 0;

while ($k < 4){
    echo "<div class='masonryImage blogImage' style='width: 300px; height:200px; background: url(" . $bloggerImgArray[$k] . ") no-repeat center; background-size:cover;'><div class='category-hover'>Filed under: News</div> <div class='caption-rollover'><a href='https://www.telecomsworldplc.co.uk/blog.twplc/no-business-can-afford-to-miss-customer-calls'>" . $bloggerArray[$k] . "</a></div></div>";
    echo "<div class='masonryImage blogImage' style='width: 300px; height:200px; background: url(" . $wpImageArray[$k] . ") no-repeat center; background-size:cover;'><div class='category-hover'>Filed under: Advice</div> <div class='caption-rollover'><a href='https://www.telecomsworldplc.co.uk/blog.twplc/no-business-can-afford-to-miss-customer-calls'>" . $wpArray[$k] . "</a></div></div>";
    echo "<div class='masonryImage tweets' style='width:300px; height:175px;'><div class='tweet-content'>" . $tweets[$k] . "</div></div>";
    $k++;
}
```

The page in question is https://www.telecomsworldplc.co.uk/testMasonryDevStatic.php

Just for reference, I have already tried `var_dump()`on the post in general, and the images are outputting fine

Comment: When you say it's `https://www.telecomsworldplc.co.uk/h` and *not* `https://www.telecomsworldplc.co.uk/advice/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/globalBusiness.jpg`, are you implying that your regex is picking up the second one?

Comment: Hi there, just to clarify, there is only one image in the post mentioned, so i'm not entirely sure where it is getting "h" from...

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

`$wpImageArray` didn't have brackets on it... So the line that fixed it was

```php
$wpImageArray[] = $wpimg;
```

It's morning, forgive me!